# What does the "@" symbol mean in a makefile when after an -I flag such as -I @mathinc@?

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm trying to understand the following line in a Makefile.in file:

`CXXFLAGS += -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=c++11 -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Isrc -I @mathinc@`

I know the `-I` flag adds a directory to the list of places where the compiler will search for included files but what does `@mathinc@` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the file is called `Makefile.in` -- this signifies that it is *input* to another file (or transformation).

In short, `configure` will run and determine, say, where the relevant include files are for `@mathinc` -- likely some math headers. After you run `configure` it will produce `Makefile` (no trailing `.in`) based on what it finds.  Do inspect that file.

`configure` scripts are created in a system called `autoconf` which, like all build systems, has its fans and its haters. There are some decent tutorials as for example [this one](http://www.idryman.org/blog/2016/03/10/autoconf-tutorial-1/).